# Java: How to check other threads' progress loading the same object

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap, java-threads

I'm fairly new to threading in Java and have been unable to find a decisive answer on this for a while. Here is a pseudocode of what I currently have:

- Three different threads: T1, T2, T3
- T1 creates a HashMap object and starts populating it with data from a DB
- T2 is then launched, and creates & starts loading a second HashMap
  object
- T3 is then launched, and does the same

Is there a reliable way to ensure one of these threads can monitor the load progress of the other threads? For example:

> After T1 and T2 have started loading data into their HashMap object,
>   T3 runs and checks the HashMap objects created by T1 and T2. It sees
>   that every 5 seconds, T1 loads 100 items into its HashMap object, and
>   T2 loads 200 items. T3 then handles this information with logic to
>   determine its own behavior, for example, sleep() until T1 and T2 have
>   both loaded 5000 items each.

What is the best Java functionality I should use to accomplish this? Would it be wise to use eventHandlers? Alternately, are there methods specific to the HashMap object class that could do the trick?

Comment: This is best done with the Observer-Pattern. 
JavaFX has the required functionality: 
javafx.collections.ObservableMap is the interface Your T1 and T2 map must implement. 
T3 implements the javafx.collections.MapChangeListener interface to receive the notifications of the ObservableMaps.

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment. That makes sense to me, but let's say in my case all three threads are loading the same object from the same class. Also, I don't know which threads will come in to load the class in what order, it would be non-deterministic in that sense. I'm not sure I could ensure that the first two threads to come in strictly load a class implementing ObservableMap and then the third strictly MapChangeListener. Could I just have the class implement both interfaces and have them all project/listen to each other?

Comment: There should only be one Observer thread that doesn't access the database. If You like to see the load order, I would make an additional thread T4 that maps the read values to a timestamp as key.